# How to change the character count result of a PHP query?

Tags: php, count, char, hide

I have created or implemented this character limiter which is common on many websites, in my case I set the limit to be 200 characters at most to be shown followed by an ellipsis.

```
$str = $row[1];
       $count = strlen($str);

       if($count<200){
       $post = $row[1];
       }else{
       $end = $count-200;
       $mod = substr($row[1], 0, -$end);
       $post = $mod."...";
       }
       if ($row[0] % 2 == 0) {
       echo 
       '<div class="background-even">'.
       $row[2].
       '<br>'.
       '<br>'.
       nl2br($post).
       '<br>'.'<br>'.
       '</div>';
       }
       else {
       echo 
       '<div class="background-odd">'.
       $row[2].
       '<br>'.
       '<br>'.
       nl2br($post).
       '<br>'.'<br>'.
       '</div>';
       }
```

What I want to do is have a button that I push like the cliche "read more" or something like that, which then shows the rest.

I can somewhat begin to think of solutions like jQuery to hide/show the rest of the content, or use the id of the post to pull the entire stored entry, I have even used a URL based query before but is there a simpler method?

Comment: Are you talking something like pagination without page refresh?

Comment: I would do this with CSS. In this way the full content is in the page, yet the Style Sheet will only render 200 characters and ellipse the rest. The 'read more' then removes the limit on that element.

Comment: @anant kumar signh, it's not a pagination, just a method of not showing everything at once, although yes extending that, pages should be had. So instead of displaying 200 characters, you push a button, and it displays all of them. I'm just wondering if I can do it via AJAX or jquery I don't know, maybe I already know the answer but don't want to implement it. If there is a simpler method.

Comment: I could pull two different versions and change which one is shown, have the height of the div element set to auto, and then use the 200 char count by default, when the button is pushed, the original version is hidden and the alternate is shown within the same div. Sounds unnecessary though. More content to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/dhbcdLL1/

Using JQuery, you can do this.

```
function truncate(t, l) {
    if (t.length > l) {
        var parts = [];
        parts[0] = t.substr(0, l - 3);
        parts[1] = t.substr(l - 3);
        return parts[0] + "..." + "<span style='display: none;'>" + parts[1] + "</span>";
    } else {
        return t;
    }
}
$(function () {
    $(".truncate").each(function () {
        $(this).html(truncate($(this).text(), 200));
    });
    $("body").on("click", "a.show-more", function () {
        var parts = $(this).prev("p").text().split("...");
        $(this).prev("p").html(parts[0] + parts[1]);
        $(this).addClass("hide-more").removeClass("show-more").html("Hide More");
    });
    $("body").on("click", "a.hide-more", function () {
        var ft = $(this).prev("p").text();
        $(this).prev("p").html(truncate(ft, 200));
        $(this).addClass("show-more").removeClass("hide-more").html("Show More");
    });
});
```

You can do the split in PHP if you want.

```
$count = strlen($row[1]);
if($count<200){
    $post = $row[1];
}else{
    $parts = array(substr($row[1], 0, 197), substr($row[1], 197));
    $post = "{$parts[0]...<span style='display: none;'>{$parts[1]}</span>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this indepth response. I see that you used jQuery I believe if I interpret the $ correctly. The PHP is interesting, I'll have to investigate further and attempt to implement (lot of random projects/busy with life). Regardless, thank you very much.